# How might synthetic video (consider star-trek holodeck) be weaponized politically in the distant future?

Tags: politics

Before we begin, a number of people have found this post confusing. Let me assure you the technology in this question does not exist. I will further justify this claim below.

A few weeks ago the New Yorker ran a story on [image and video synthesis](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2018/11/12/in-the-age-of-ai-is-seeing-still-believing). The article discusses some of the technical aspects involved in verifying legitimate images, creating new video from old footage, and some of the social aspects surrounding these issues. There's a proof of concept video at the end showing some of the technical work ("Using artificial intelligence, researchers can project the movements of one body onto another’s"), where a video of a dancer, and some initial footage of the author is used to create a video of him dancing. The article makes it clear that creating arbitrary realistic video is still a long ways off.

Suppose there is an earth-like world some 10 or 20 or 50 years in the future such that this technology has matured (audio synthesis is implicitly assumed). I will call this *deepfake*: when a synthetic video can not be distinguished from a "natural" video by common citizens using consumer products. Because people find this concept confusing, let me offer an analogy. This technology is equivalent to the Star Trek holodeck, except it's only viewable on a 2d screen, not an immersive program.

Several users have suggested such technology is already available. There is no current technology that allows anyone to create a video of a person performing arbitrary actions, or [saying arbitrary things](https://www.extremetech.com/extreme/267771-buzzfeed-created-a-deepfake-obama-psa-video). The current [state of the art](https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.07371) video creation is jerky and obvious. It probably requires specialized hardware. There is no public software to create such videos. Now, imagine sometime in the future. Software has gotten a lot more advanced, and can offer helpful suggestions. Imagine a video creation app you can download for free from the android app store, something similar to google's https://www.autodraw.com/ where with only some gentle coaxing you could create a video of anything you want. Star Trek example again:

> [Outside holodeck]
>
> (The friends are costumed for late Victorian London)
> DATA: Computer, select at random a mystery by Sir Arthur Conan Doyle, where I will play Sherlock Holmes and Lieutenant La Forge will be Doctor John Watson.
> COMPUTER: Programme complete. You may enter.

http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/129.htm

Except, for the purposes of this question, the technology is not an immersive interactive video like the holodeck.

If I were to show this technology of the future to Bart Simpson today, you can imagine the kind of simple but relatively harmless prank videos that might be created. Someone more cynical might imagine some sinister videos that might be made about a political opponent. (I think we are somewhere close to this point in time where this technology causes some concern, but this question is a skeptical challenge to this future concern).

But what about society in the future? I propose that if this technology exists in the future and is easily accessible, that it won't really be used for harm (this is my question). Basically, if fake videos are common, then no one will expect any negative video *on it's own* to hold much value. Similar to how verbal claims require other evidence to be taken seriously.

I imagine there will be some conspiracy theory use cases (just like today with text or images), and some tabloid use cases (just like today with text or images), but other than that, are there other reasons society should be concerned? Are there any side effects? Are there subtle use cases outside of an "obvious" conspiracy theory (assume that the majority of people would call it "obvious")? Perhaps conspiracy theory state-sponsored psy-ops will evolve to something new, different than it is today?

Consider a future where this technology is common as outlined above.  Well, for one thing, if it's so common then synthetic videos will be ordinary, mundane, uninteresting. Anyone can make a video. No skill required. Just like https://www.autodraw.com/ Creating a compromising video of a political opponent will amount to nothing. Release a damaging video of President Millhouse? No one cares, because there are hundreds more just like it. Sure, there are a few people that fall for some conspiracy theories, but most people will just roll their eyes, the same way that most people don't believe in batboy in the checkout line tabloid. So how will this be useful?

---

**Possible Answers**

Let me sketch an outline of what answers might look like. I will start with some negative examples.

Bad Answer: Politicians will create damaging videos of opponents.
Explanation: This is a bad answer for several reasons. It assumes that this hypothetical future world is exactly the same as today. It ignores the fact that anyone can create a  video. It doesn't explain why only some people (politicians) would create video, and further doesn't explain why that will be widely believed.

Bad Answer: This technology already exists.
Explanation: The most familiar example I can think of is the Star Trek holodeck. There is absolutely nothing remotely like that which currently exists.

Bad Answer: People can already create movies of anything.
Explanation: While somewhat true, this requires enormous quantities of some combination of the following: technical expertise with specialized software (video and photo editors); specialized hardware (rendering  farms, servers, GPUs); movie studios with props, actors, set creators, artists; large amounts of time (to plan, create, execute, edit, post-production, render). These are all substantial barriers which this question assumes no longer exist.

.

Ok, and a rough sketch of what I think possible answers will look like. But I want to say, one of the joys of worldbuilding is how unexpected answers sometimes pop up, so I don't think this captures all possible answers.

Good Answer: (null hypothesis) Synthetic videos will become pointless in terms of political damage.
Explanation: This is more or less what is outlined in the question. (See, for instance, a related question: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/207640/how-do-living-politicians-protect-their-readily-obtainable-signatures-from-misus )

Good Answer: Politicians will create damaging videos of opponents. Despite the fact that anyone can create a video, this will matter because [reasons].
Explanation: This answer would probably discuss human  psychology. There'd be a discussion of confirmation bias. Some discussion about how people double down when expose to contrary beliefs. Maybe a history of how political propaganda isn't designed to persuade *everyone*, it's only meant to impact a few percent who are undecided. I think this more or less boils down to a comparison with text: anyone can write anything about anyone, and look how that's turned out.

Good Answer: No one will create blatant false videos. Instead, synthetic videos will become more targeted.
Explanation: This answer is more or less focused on "truthful" videos. Maybe this answer predicts that feedback from psychology, sociology, and marketing will go into video creation. Imagine watching a debate between two political candidates, and during the commercial break, a 20 second campaign ad is created and played. Some analysis has been performed, it is statistically likely you will receive a small dopamine hit when a video featuring [some combination] of phrases and campaign points is played, featuring Candidate X. Of course, the computer model considered but decided against, playing a negative attack ad on Candidate Y that was likely to trigger an imperceptible emotional response of fear and disgust, because that ad had a smaller statistical likelihood of you voting for Candidate X. And further, because ad tracking knows that earlier today you spent around 3 minutes browsing that NYTimes article about the importance of [political issue Z], the dynamically created campaign ad features a subtle reference to [issue Z], triggering "inside group" recognition with Candidate X, making you more likely to associate with Candidate X in the future.

Good Answer: People will still create false videos because "truth takes time."
Explanation: Perhaps this answer theorizes that a verification service exists, a faster, better, more automated snopes. But still, rumors can spread very quickly, and the truth is usually pretty boring. That is, if a retraction or a correction is released a day later, it may be too late for people to notice or care. I think this is the hardest answer to justify, because you'll have to consider aspects of the above answers I outlined, but I think this is still plausible.

But these are just rough outlines of my thoughts, I don't expect actual answers to look exactly like this.

**Question**: How might deepfake video be weaponized politically in a world where access to that technology is common? (A world that doesn't currently exist; where people have grown up with this technology and anyone, even your tech illiterate grandmother, can create a video about anything)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86750/discussion-on-question-by-burnsba-how-might-deepfake-video-be-weaponized-politic).

Comment: The answer is 1993 movie Rising Sun with Wesley Snipes and Sean Connery.

Comment: The Star Trek DS9 episode "In the Pale Moonlight" deals with this idea.  Specifically, the forged holographic display is not initially accepted because the ambassador who needed to look it over spotted the flaws... but the flaws could be explained by damage that occurred in the detonation of a shuttle... which just happened to occur when the ambassador left... and upon investigation, his government found the document and played right into our hero's hands.  Will go in depth as to why if reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it would be weaponized any more than email is right now.

It's trivial to spoof an email from someone, or a web posting, or anything at all, yet the real-world impact is minimal because people (well, except for people pre-disposed to believe such things anyway) realize that the text by itself doesn't necessarily mean anything. Greater context and additional proof would be necessary.

Look at it this way: it's been possible for years to make a nearly perfect, 100% realistic video of a UFO. People can do it on home computers with off-the-shelf software and a small amount of effort (hell, some programs come with built-in capabilities to do specifically that sort of thing). Yet despite this, while belief in aliens visiting Earth goes up and down, it hasn't significantly increased from [polling back in the day before such video tech was available](https://www.livescience.com/21216-americans-ufo-belief.html) and photos that showed a UFO as a physical object were faked with lamps, hubcaps, and models hanging from strings.

So why not? Because people realize those photos and videos can be faked. We've all seen movies and TV shows.

So if the DeepFake tech gets good enough, people are going to be aware of it and be suitably skeptical when (noted politician) shows up in a video doing something if that video is not accompanies by additional evidence.

Comment: "Because people realize those photos and videos can be faked." Everybody is wise to the deception is the naive view that has gotten dictators entrenched in power and resulted in millions of deaths. For evidence - look up "propaganda". Consider the broad potential effects of Stockholm-Syndrome.

Comment: @Duck People have been using propaganda and rhetoric to their advantage since when the state of the art in information dispersal was going up to somebody and talking to them, but has it gotten *more* effective?

Comment: @Cadence I believe so yes, since methods of broad economic and social control have become more effective in eliminating free speach in some societies. (To a large extent not the west, again ... yet, it's damned well being erroded though). What censorship exists on your newsfeeds? and how could you possibly know about it if everyone else in your social media bubble has the same censorship??? What if The internet in your country is "expurgated" for anything the incumbent regime doesn't like? 1984 is a classic for a reason.

Comment: How often do you send people emails compared to videos or pictures on social media? When you watch or read a story on social media do you ever check its authenticity?

Comment: hmmm, an on-topic relevant answer that adds to the discussion, not sure why you're downvoted.

Comment: I haven't voted on this but I think there's fundamentally something different in the believability of ghost/alien/big foot videos and known public figures that really renders that part of your argument moot

Comment: @BurnsBA Maybe the downvote came from "The Chairman."

Comment: @BKlassen when I see a story on social media, I check where it is from.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Today, any graphic designer can photoshop a politician shaking hands with a criminal or dictator. Do you see it happening? Would anybody believe it if they saw it at some random website? No, the pic would only have impact it if an establish news organization posted it, and confirmed that picture is genuine, e.g. by finding reliable eyewitnesses, other pictures of the same meeting, checking if both people were elsewhere at supposed time of meeting, etc.

Comment: @Bald Bear Doesn't that make you a shill of the technocracy - or possibly a bot? Seriously, the Turing test needs to be applied to all interactions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test . Or maybe we're in the matrix - and the Turing Test is being applied to us!

Comment: @Duckisaduckisaduck Why? I am promoting human sources over generated videos. Besides, Turing Test is useless: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_test#Human_misidentification

Comment: @Bald Bear Damn, you blew my cover as a competing machine.

Answer (score 2):

There are too many ways to even begin listing all the ways in which deepfake videos could cause political harm. From creating believable slander to glorifying yourself and everything in between.

Let's just look at the prevalence of memes and viral videos and how quickly those get sent around, most people don't bother to do the research behind a video and so can explosively spread misinformation.

To give an example let's say you are a CEO of athletic gear and your competitor who has been rising in popularity due to their lower prices. Using deepfake you leak a video showing your competitor's factory using child labor, that gets passed around by millions of people without thinking to check if its real and suddenly your competitor is so bogged down with disproving the video your sales rocket.

Comment: That might happen if the CEO is the only one that can create videos. But what if anyone can? "Oh **another** child labor video. /yawn."

Comment: @BurnsBA just because anyone can doesn't mean people would invest the time to do it. Anyone can learn how to photoshop and edit videos even today, but how many people really do?

Comment: that's a good point, I had some implicit assumptions about the future of technology, see my edits where I spell out how technology becomes easier to use.

Comment: Plenty of people can photoshop or stage pictures now, or write incorrect descriptions. Snope.com is full of examples. The end result is that nobody believes a picture from a random source, and respectable news organizations can only maintain their reputation by investigating and verify the photos that publish.

Comment: @BaldBear we're at a point already though with social media that news organizations are hardly the only ones posting things and it's not as though news organizations never get it wrong

Answer (score 0):

It's simply a war of resources - in other words wealth. A news channel wants a story, they deep-fake it.

A corrupt politician wants to dispose of an opponent, they deep-fake his suicide but actually have him murdered.

The only people to suffer are those with a lower income. Either they don't have the funds or the skills to do it. Blackmail is rife. False accusations are 'proved' in court.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough in my question, I'm assuming this is common technology that anyone can use. I tried to clarify my question, because I don't think this answer addresses that at all.